# Rails: could not find a valid mapping for nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise

I'm getting this error quite frequently. In my application controller I have a method named `after_sign_in_path_for` redirecting a user after he signed in with his account (Devise).
Here is the line causing the error:

```
request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || root_url
```

Shouldn't that just fall back to `root_url` if the two previous options do not work?

---

Specificly after signing in with Google (Omniauth), I encounter this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code for `stored_location_for(resource)` it eventually calls this piece of magic. `obj` here is the `resource`, so if that's `nil` it raises the error you encounter, so it never falls back to `root_path`

```
def self.find_scope!(obj)
  obj = obj.devise_scope if obj.respond_to?(:devise_scope)
  case obj
  when String, Symbol
    return obj.to_sym
  when Class
    Devise.mappings.each_value { |m| return m.name if obj <= m.to }
  else
    Devise.mappings.each_value { |m| return m.name if obj.is_a?(m.to) }
  end

  raise "Could not find a valid mapping for #{obj.inspect}"
end
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/mapping.rb